# Avoid empty wrappers for same hashtags in a html label element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have created custom Javascript/JQuery code to find hashtags in a string appear in a html label. I'm highlighting those hashtags and add wrapper around them. But, if same hashtag string shows in 2 labels there's a strange empty wrapper added in front of the hashtag and appear in label content. how to avoid that empty wrapper and is this a good idea to search for hashtag strings or will this cause to site loading speed?

Here's my code to split hashtags in a string and adding wrapper around them:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $status_hash = $('.hashtag').text();

    var tagslistarr = $status_hash.split(' ');
    var arr=[];
    $.each(tagslistarr,function(i,val){
        if(tagslistarr[i].indexOf('#') == 0){
          arr.push(tagslistarr[i]);  
        }
    });

    for($x=0; $x<=arr.length;$x++){
        $(".hashtag:contains('"+arr[$x]+"')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.split(arr[$x]).join("<a href='#' class='smallcaps' style='text-decoration:none; background-color:rgba(113, 162, 252, 0.63); color:white; padding:2px 4px 2px 4px; border-radius:2px;'>"+arr[$x]+"</a>");
        });
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle(UPDATED)

[**Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishan152/ptwmjcep/) http://jsfiddle.net/Nishan152/ptwmjcep/

Comment: ***.... if same hashtag string shows in 2 labels ....***! What do you mean? Can you show an example?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question? Is requirement to wrap all text beginning with `#` with `a` element having `#` target , or `#hastag` target ?

Comment: @PeterKA I have given JSfiddle example at the bottom of the code snippet..

Comment: @guest271314 I'm using CI, I want to add wrappers and highlight hashtag elements with `a` elements inside `html label` elements. So, I can give `a` element target to my controller to search the specific `#` tag text.

Comment: @PeterKA In the demo there are two `#test` and `#label` hashtags. In the result there's a strange `a` element append in front of both `#test` hashtag elements. I want to avoid that strange empty `a` elements from my `label` elements.

Comment: Quick "cleanup" , without attempting to _not_ append element  http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ptwmjcep/12/ ? can include `html` at jsfiddle at original post ?

Comment: @guest271314 This would be ok since it's unnecessary to show empty `#` highlights inside `label` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not need that many operations to do that kind of wrapping or just to extract the hash tags.

To get the hash tags you can use this one-liner:

```
var arr = $.grep( $('.hashtag').text().split(' '), function( v, i ) {
    return v.charAt(0) === '#';
});
```

But if all you want is to wrap the tags here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $('.hashtag').html(function(_,html) {
        return html.replace(/(\#[a-z]+)/gi, function(x) {
            return "<a href='#' class='smallcaps' style='text-decoration:none; background-color:rgba(113, 162, 252, 0.63); color:white; padding:2px 4px 2px 4px; border-radius:2px;'>" + x + "</a>";
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ptwmjcep/16/)

Comment: @NishanWeerasinghe This answer is more concise. Expected result can be returned without extra call to `.map()` , utilizing only `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".hashtag").map(function(i, el) {
    $(el).html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(/(#\w+)/g, function(match) {
          return "<a href=# class=smallcaps "
          + "style=text-decoration:none;"
          + "background-color:rgba(113,162,252,0.63);"
          + "color:white;padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;"
          + "border-radius:2px;>" + match + "</a>"
        })
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ptwmjcep/15/

See [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) , [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)